# Button to download image from url created by user

Tags: android

Ok, I'm editing this as I have thought of an easier way, its just trying to implement it. I have seen some code that I thought could work, modified it to what I need it for but I'm having a few issues. What needs to be done is that the button needs to initiate a download.

The code I have is '                    /** Called when the user clicks the Get My Image button */
    Button viewimagebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imagedownloader);
    viewimagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

```
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         boolean success = (new File("/sdcard/dirname")).mkdir(); 
         if (!success)
         {
             Log.w("directory not created", "directory not created");
         }

         try
         {
             final String baseUrl = "http://flickholdr.com/";
             EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pixelw);
             EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pixelh);
                     EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pixels);
                     EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.picnumber);
     String baseUrl1 = baseUrl1 + editText1.getText().toString() + "/"
             + editText2.getText().toString() + "/"
             + editText3.getText().toString() + "/"
             + editText4.getText().toString() + "/";     
             HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl1.openConnection();
             connection.setDoInput(true);
             connection.connect();
             InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
             Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

             String data1 = String.valueOf(String.format("/sdcard/dirname/%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis()));

             FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(data1);

             ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outstream);
             byte[] byteArray = outstream.toByteArray();

             stream.write(byteArray);
             stream.close();

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 });


    }



    ;});
    };{;}}'
```

but on the line

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl1.openConnection();

I get an error of "the method openConnection() is undefined for the type string.

If someone could advise on what is going wrong that would be great. I will be changing the name of the directory in which the file saves.

Many Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Passing String to new Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ToClass.class);
intent.putExtra("url", "http://..");
startActivity(i); 

Intent intent = getIntent();
String url = intent.getExtras().getString("url");
```

Comment: I have input that, but when I click the button, nothing happens still

Comment: do the following. try to show the image in the same activity not in a new one. if that worked. log.i the url on the new activity. and check if you got that right.